# Parameter not working for varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SQL code below returns the value 4.68

```
select Top 1 [Price_per_KG_AES001] as [(316) 401 - 600] From [dbo].[tbl_stock_list] where [GRADE] = '316'
```

When I make the Customer a parameter variable, the SQL below returns Price_per_KG_AES001

```
Declare @TheCustomer varchar(50) = 'Price_per_KG_AES001'
select Top 1 @TheCustomer  as [(316) 401 - 600] From [dbo].[tbl_stock_list] where [GRADE] = '316'
```

How do I amend the code to return the 4.68 using the variable?

Comment: @gsa sqlserver of cause

Comment: I wants the column selected to be determined by the content of the variable. [Price_per_KG_AES001] is the name of the column. However this may change so need a variable @Customer to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL, the current syntax seems doesn't work.

So, you need :

```
Declare @TheCustomer varchar(50) = 'Price_per_KG_AES001'
declare @sql varchar(500)

set @sql = 'select Top 1 '+ @TheCustomer +'  as [(316) 401 - 600] 
            from [dbo].[tbl_stock_list] 
            where [GRADE] = ''316'' '
print @sql -- to see how your query looks before execution 

exec (@sql);
```

Comment: This did not resolve the issue. Sorry If my original post was not clear.

Comment: 'Price_per_KG_AES001' is the name of a column

Comment: The OP wants the column selected to be determined by the content of the variable.  So, you're right, Dynamic SQL is required, but what you've written isn't dynamic SQL.

Comment: You are correct MatBailie, that is what I am after. How do I do the dynamic SQL to achieve the column selected to be determined by the content of the variable?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is substitute the contents of your variable in to your query, then execute it.

Something like this...

```
DECLARE
  @TheCustomer   VARCHAR(50) = 'Price_per_KG_AES001',
  @sql_statement VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql_statement = 'select Top 1 ' + @TheCustomer + ' as [(316) 401 - 600] From [dbo].[tbl_stock_list] where [GRADE] = ''316''' 

EXEC @sql_statement
```

*( Also, look into parameterised queries with `sp_executesql` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 )*

But if anyone ever manages to "hack" the contents of that variable, and put some SQL in it, you'll execute their SQL.  See SQL Injection Attack.

The SAFE ways to protect yourself are you create a white list of allowable values.  Only if the variable contents is in the list do you proceed.

Or, just use a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT
  TOP(1)
  CASE WHEN @var = 'x' THEN table.x
       WHEN @var = 'y' THEN table.y
       WHEN @var = 'z' THEN table.z END AS column_alias
FROM
  table
```